# White lines appear when I open a modal

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

I use modals in my every day coding but know suddenly this white lines appear, what could it be?

[image: White line like is show in the picture]

Just edit my post, sorry im new in here, here is my code, i add the modal body by jquery because i get the data via ajax, jquery code

This code comes in respoonde of the ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: route,
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data){
```

...

```
switch (extension){
            case 'pdf':
                storage = storage.replace('archivo', data.documento.ubicacion);
                console.log(storage);

                html = '<div class="row">'+
                    '<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> '+
                    '<div id="doc"></div>'+
                    '</div>'+

                    '</div>';

                $('#liDocumento').append(html);
                PDFObject.embed(storage, "#doc");
                break;
            case "png":
            case "PNG":
            case "jpg":
            case "JPG":
                storage = storage.replace('archivo', data.documento.ubicacion);

                html = '<div class="row">'+
                    '<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> '+
                    '<img src="'+storage+'" style="width: 100%;">'+

                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>';

                $('#hrefDescargar').attr('href',routeDescarga);
                $('#hrefDescargar').removeClass("hidden");

                $('#liDocumento').append(html);

                break;
            default:
                console.log("OTROS");

                html = '<div class="row">'+
                    '<div class="media">'+
                    '<div class="media-left media-middle text-center">'+

                    '<img class="media-object" src="/images/archivo.png" width="180" height="180">'+

                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="media-body">'+
                    '<h4 class="media-heading">'+data.documento.nombre+'</h4>'+
                    '<p><b>Referencia: </b>'+data.referencia+'</p>'+
                    '<p><b>Documento de: </b>'+data.documento.tipo.nombre+'</p>'+
                    '<p><b>Numero de hojas: </b>'+data.num_hojas+'</p>'+
                    '<p><b>Tipo de doc.: </b>'+data.tipo.nombre+'</p>'+
                    '<p><b>Copias: </b>'+copias+'</p>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>';

                $('#hrefDescargar').attr('href',routeDescarga);
                $('#hrefDescargar').removeClass("hidden");

                $('#liDocumento').append(html);
                break;
        }
```

In the appends **$('#liDocumento').append(html)** i add the code, i use the pdfobjet to when is pdf **script src="/js/pdfobject.js"**
Then the modal is shown

```
$('#modalCorrespondencia').modal('show');
```

Comment: you sholud provide your code, nobody can guess what is causing that without a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code.

Comment: Possibly a td outside a table? right-click on it and click inspect

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]_

Comment: Just edit my question, sorry i`m new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the modal position to fixed instead of absolute, and give it bigger z-index.